# extract strings using regex python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have text in a file that I am pushing into a string.

```
txt = "PRIMARY INDEX its_mnth_content_aggr ( AC_ID ,ROW_ADDED_DT ,NOTE_SEQ_NR ,BIZ_UNIT_CD ,
DISPATCH_ID ,CASE_CREATE_DT ) 
ABDCGFWERRUU 
asdffggb 
PRIMARY INDEX its_mnth_content_aggr ( AC_CASE ,ROW_ADDED_DT ,NOTE_SEQ_NR ,BIZ_UNIT_CD ,\
DISPATCH_ID ,CASE_CREATE_DT )"
```

I want to extract the complete primary index from it as in primary index (....)

so far i have below

```
x3 = re.findall(r"\bPRIMARY\sINDEX\s\w+\W.*", txt)
```

that gives me

```
['PRIMARY INDEX its_mnth_content_aggr ( AC_CASE_ID ,ROW_ADDED_DT ,NOTE_SEQ_NR ,BIZ_UNIT_CD ,DISPATCH_ID ,CASE_CREATE_DT )  ABDCGFWERRUU  qwerrtyyuiu PRIMARY INDEX its_mnth_content_aggr ( AC_CASE_ID ,ROW_ADDED_DT ,NOTE_SEQ_NR ,BIZ_UNIT_CD ,DISPATCH_ID ,CASE_CREATE_DT )']
```

I want something like this

```
['PRIMARY INDEX its_mnth_content_aggr ( AC_CASE_ID ,ROW_ADDED_DT ,NOTE_SEQ_NR ,BIZ_UNIT_CD ,DISPATCH_ID ,CASE_CREATE_DT ) PRIMARY INDEX its_mnth_content_aggr ( AC_CASE_ID ,ROW_ADDED_DT ,NOTE_SEQ_NR ,BIZ_UNIT_CD ,DISPATCH_ID ,CASE_CREATE_DT )']
```

can someone please help

Comment: Also, my string is includes newlines between Primary index values

Comment: `r'\bPRIMARY\s+INDEX\s+\w+\s*\([^()]*\)'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regex says that you want a string that starts by `PRIMARY INDEX` followed by any characters. So it matches all your string;

---

You have to be more specific.

```
PRIMARY INDEX[A-Za-z(_,\n\\ ]*\)
```

- the string should start with: `PRIMARY INDEX`
- then there could be any letter or special characters in `[A-Za-z(_,\n\\ ]`, followed by `*` because we don't know the number of these characters.
- and it ends by a `)`

You can  try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/vcMCQZ/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
re.findall(r'\bPRIMARY\s+INDEX\s+\w+\s*\([^()]*\)', txt)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GZ6LSb/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `PRIMARY\s+INDEX` - `PRIMARY`, 1+ whitespaces, `INDEX`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.